# Issues drawing multiple image textures with some disapearing

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm looking to use OpenGl to blend 4 images to the screen. The first image contains the background and the other 3 are images contain some cartoon with transparency. My goal is to render those 4 images at once. At every call to render I'm updating the top 3 images with new images to compose the new frame.

I'm new to OpenGL and so far I'm able to achieve blending those images however I'm noticing some horrible issues when I render. I'm seeing some of the top 3 images are missing sometimes or some are rendered but look like they where cropped by the invisible man...

Each lines represents a different image.

Image cropped issue:
[image]

Image cropped and one image missing:
[image]

How it should look like:
[image]

Any help figuring out the issue I would greatly appreciate it! Below the code I'm using.

Here is the code I use to render the images.

```
void MoviePreview::prepareTexture (GLuint texture, GLint format, int w, int h)
{
    // Bind to generated texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,  GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    //glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, w, h, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    if (GL_RGBA == format)
    {
        //glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    // Crop the texture rectangle
    GLint rect[] = {0, h, w, -h};
    glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, rect);
    glDrawTexiOES(0, 0, 0, w, h);
}

void MoviePreview::resize (int w, int h)
{
    LOGI("native_gl_resize %d %d", w, h);

    // init open gl
    //glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_DITHER);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glDisable(GL_FOG);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_COLOR_LOGIC_OP);
    glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);

    //glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);//NEW
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);//NEW
    //glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);

    // Generate one texture object
    glGenTextures(MAX_TEXTURES, mTexture);
    check_gl_error("glGenTextures");

    int frameHeight = h;//image.rows;
    int frameWidth = w;//image.cols;

    // first texture is our background texture
    prepareTexture(mTexture[0], GL_RGBA, mBg.cols, mBg.rows);
    prepareTexture(mTexture[1], GL_RGBA, frameWidth, frameHeight);
    prepareTexture(mTexture[2], GL_RGBA, frameWidth, frameHeight);
    prepareTexture(mTexture[3], GL_RGBA, frameWidth, frameHeight);

    mSurfaceWidth = w;
    mSurfaceHeight = h;
}

void MoviePreview::render (int64_t* imageIds, const int images)
{
    int i                   = 0;
    double sleepDuration    = 0;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // TODO try to see if we can just get away from always loading the bg
    // since it doesn't change often might be worth loading it once and that
    // is it...
    //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexture[0]);
    //glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, mBg.cols, mBg.rows, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mBg.ptr());
    //glDrawTexiOES(0, 0, 0, mSurfaceWidth, mSurfaceHeight);

    // TODO pass the image batch loader
    // load images
    for (i=0; i<images; i++)
    {
        if (0 < imageIds[i])
        {
            sprintf(mTempPath, "%s/f1_%lld.png",mProjectPath.c_str(), imageIds[i]);
            mImageLoader[i].loadImage(mTempPath);
        }
    }

    if (0 < mFrameDuration)
    {
        // here we try to control the suggested frame rate
        // set. We calculate since the last show image time
        // if we should sleep or not...
        if (0 < mLastDrawTimestamp) {
            sleepDuration = mFrameDuration - (now_ms() - mLastDrawTimestamp);
        }

        if (0 < sleepDuration) {
            usleep((long)sleepDuration*NANO_IN_MS);
        }
    }

    // draw images
    i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<images; i++)
    {
        if (0 < imageIds[i])
        {
            cv::Mat img = mImageLoader[i].getImage();
            if (!img.empty())
            {
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexture[i+1]);
                glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, img.cols, img.rows, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.ptr());
                glDrawTexiOES(0, 0, 0, img.cols, img.rows);
            }
        }
    }

    mLastDrawTimestamp = now_ms();
}
```

Comment: Could it be Z-fighting?

Comment: I guess it wouldn't be Z-fighting since I'm using GL_TEXTURE_2D? It's a none 3D deal but maybe there are settings I'm not aware of?

Comment: OpenGL has no 2D mode. Everything is 3D. To rule out z-fighting try setting the z-coordinates of your sprites to different values and see if you sill get the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being with my image sources getting modified by another thread while OpenGl was trying to draw them...